# Screen Blink when moving mouse after inactivity

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, 17.04

I have a ThinkPad Yoga 14 20FY with the following specs

- i5-6200U
- Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
- Nvidia GeForce 940M

I am running Ubuntu 17.04 with the latest updates.

I noticed an issue that manifests when the machine has been sitting for a couple of minutes. If I move the mouse cursor, whether through the touchpad, trackpoint, touchscreen, or external mouse, the screen blinks briefly.  I tried installing a newer kernel, but that just added other graphical issues on top of the blinking.

I'm not entirely sure what would cause this, I think it might be GPU related, but not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue with Gnome 3 in Debian, it drove me so mad that I switch everything and went to Arch with KDE,but instead of screen flickering it was displaying "No External Display" message. But, as you said I was thinking that was something related to my touchpad, and it really was, my touchpad it's a Alps one that comes with my Dell, I only was able to fix this issue installing it's driver using DKMS, I followed the instructions in the link bellow, I hope it helps you, it's really annoying:

http://ayushyajaiswal.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/installing-alps-multitouch-drivers-in.html

Comment: I ended up reinstalling windows because linux was having other issues(poor power management mostly). The flicker dissappeared after I updated the kernel and mesa drivers though.